# Was there a time when Montenegro executed all of its millionaires?

Tags: europe

I bought the complete works of [G. K. Chesterton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._K._Chesterton) for $1 for my Kindle and read them. Somewhere in all those volumes (as I remember) he asserts that Montenegro executed all of its millionaires (and thereby solved almost all their problems). He was writing 100 years ago. I know that, today, Montenegro is a haven for Millionaires.

I have tried to verify Chesterton's statement using Google. I can't find a hint of a time when the country had some sort of revolution and killed all the millionaires. And I can't find the exact volume in my Chesterton collection so I can check my memory.

So my question is:  In its past, did Montenegro kill all its millionaires?

Edit:  Thanks to @kimchilover the passage is found.  In *The Crimes of England* Chesterton writes,

> "In Montenegro there are no millionaires–and therefore next to no Socialists. As to why there are no millionaires, it is a mystery, and best studied among the mysteries of the Middle Ages. By some of the dark ingenuities of that age of priestcraft a curious thing was discovered–that if you kill every usurer, every forestaller, every adulterater, every user of false weights, every fixer of false boundaries, every land-thief, every water-thief, you afterwards discover by a strange indirect miracle, or disconnected truth from heaven, that you have no millionaires."

Comment: Interesting question! I haven't a clue how true that assertion is, but remember that a millionaire in 1920s Montenegro would have been a *very* different thing than one in a modern society. This was a rural society with little industry, so that their millions would have come mostly from landholdings. Today, a reasonable fraction of hundred-millionaires (modern equiv. value) got their money from having done something that people willingly paid for. In a pre-modern society, a millionaire was much more likely to be a rentier, and not necessarily ever a productive member of society.

Comment: So Chesterton did never claim that all millionaires were killed, but only that the abundant administration of the death penalty to (what in his mind are) criminals had the side effect of preventing the accumulatin of wealth. The whole thing looks to me as a reference to the rule of [Šćepan Mali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0%C4%87epan_Mali) in the 17th century. He was known both as falsly claiming to be the deposed Russian czar Peter III., and for bringing unity to the country's clans. And he introduced the death penalty, alledgedly handing it out almost two hundred times.

Comment: Actually the 18th century, according to the link provided - 1768-73.